# How to make an android view visible across the application?

Tags: android

I have a DrawingLayout on my android app's landing page. I want to make it visible throughout the application so that I can use that as navigation control for my app. Is it possible? If Yes, how can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think the best approach which I can think of is to create your custom view, attach it to your main layout and than use Fragments. This way you will have one Activity, one custom View and as many Fragments as you want to create the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `DrawingLayout` in each of your activities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But apart from this, there is no concept/feature in android which allows us to achieve this?

Comment: In Android, each Activity is an independent activity, and there's no trivial way to do what you want. Marks' answer, although terse, is essentially correct. I recommend that you create a "base class" that's a subclass of activity, and then make all your other activities a subclass of this one. Then write your base class to look for a DrawingLayout and handle it properly. That way, you won't have to re-write the handler for every Activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edward. That's really a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

create a class which return a Linear layout containing all your navigation controls which you want on your application screens and add that to your activity by method addView(lin_layout);

look at this

```
    public class yourClass{
        Context context;
        public LinearLayout createNavBar(int tooBarHeight,String mTitle, Context mContext)
        {

           LinearLayout topBar = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            topBar.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            topBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,tooBarHeight));   
            topBar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

            TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width - 2*tooBarHeight,tooBarHeight));
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            text.setText(mTitle);
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            text.setPadding(15, 10, 0, 0);
            text.setTextSize(18);

            topBar.addView(text);

            Button home = new Button(mContext);
            home.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(tooBarHeight,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            //home.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            home.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            topBar.addView(home);

            home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            });

            Button order = new Button(mContext);
            order.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(tooBarHeight,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));    
            order.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            //order.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15); 
            topBar.addView(order);

            order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            });

            return topBar;  
       }
```

}
you can add this nav bar to your activity by

```
yourClass toolbar = new yourClass();
            LinearLayout topBar  = toolbar.createNavBar(72,"your title", mContext);         
            this.addView(topBar);
```